# Grails - Spring security - ajax login

Tags: jquery, grails, spring-security

```
 $(function() {
        $('#btnPush').on('click', function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://domain.com/j_spring_security_check',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    j_username: 'username',
                    j_password: 'password'
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    alert('Login Success');
                },
                error: function(jqXHR) {
                    alert('Login Fail');
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

The above code works (i.e the user login is success)  if the page is with in the project.

If the code is out side of the project (which is what we need), it is not working. it shows `302 Moved Temporarily` error.

How to login to the project from another project in grails with spring security.

Comment: it may not work because, it looks like a cross domain request which is not allowed by the [Same Origin Policy](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy). one possible solution is to enable [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-cors-20090317/)

Comment: ..... and for that you have [CORS plugin in grails](http://grails.org/plugin/cors).

Comment: You can use JSONP, if you set your spring security to allow GET login request.